# Measure of $f(C)$ where $f$ is the Cantor function and $C$ is the Cantor set.

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to figure out what is the Lebesgue measure of $f(C)$. I am not quite sure if that set is even measurable as $f$ is not $1-1$ and so it does not have a continuous inverse. My "idea" was that the whole image is $[0,1]$ and the points in $C^c$ only contribute countable amount of points to the image. Hence $f(C)$ has measure 1. How do i formalize this.

Comment: What is $C^c$? Either way, yes, it is true that $f(C)=[0,1]$. You can see this by considering where the endpoints of all the intervals in the construction of $C$ go, and then using the fact that $f(C)$ is compact (since $C$ is) and hence closed.

Comment: @Wojowu $C^c$ is the complement of the cantor set :P. Yeah so there are countable endpoints, correct? Therefore the image of $C^c$ is simply countable amount of points. Is that correct? I agree that $f(C)$ is compact but i am not sure how you are using that.

Comment: There are countably many endpoints, yes, but $C^c$ is very much uncountable, since it is a union of open intervals.

Comment: @Wojowu yes, but their image under the cantor function, is countable.

Answer (score 1):

All you really need to do is show that $f$ is onto. So, first we settle the question of what to do when an element of $[0, 1] = I$ has two ternary expansions. We agree to use the one that has only the digits $0$ and $2$. Then $C$ consists of all $x\in I$ whose ternary expansion has only $0$ and $2$ in it. Then, if $ x_0 = (.a_1 a_2 a_3 \cdots )_3,\ f(x_0)=(.\frac{a_1}{2} \frac{a_2}{2}\frac{a_3}{2} \cdots )_2$. It follows fron this that if $y=(.b_1 b_2 b_3 \cdots )_2\in I,\ $ then $f((.2b_1 2b_2 2b_3 \cdots )_3)=y$.